# Transform two dimensional array into a single one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am querying some data in my node.js server, I want the result to be a simple array of strings but when i print it it comes out like this:

`[
  ['element1'],[element2'],['element3']
]`

instead of just `['element1',element2','element3]`

Instinctively i tried to print array[0] but that just prints out the first element and not the first dimension of my array.

im relatively new to javascript and i really don't understand this behavior.

Help is very appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, are you sure it's a nested array in the first place?

Comment: Can you show code please

Comment: So your problem is your output is in the wrong format? modify the return value of the callee or just loop through the nested array you already have. If the former, you'll have to provide more code.

Answer (score 1):

If your nested array is like that:

```
var nested = [
  ['element1','1'],['element2','2'],['element3','3']
];
```

Then you can flatten it using [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like that:

```
var flat = nested.reduce(function(p, c) { return p.concat(c); }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to get the first element from each inner array like this:

```js
var newArray = [
  ['element1'],['element2'],['element3']
].map(function(i) {
  return i[0];
  });
```